# Java sliding puzzle, know when finished?

Tags: java, swing, button, puzzle

I am making a java sliding puzzle for class, and so far, I am able to get the picture to be cropped, and I have found a way to slide all the buttons via the action listener. At this point, however, I cannot fathom as to how to check to see if all of the buttons are in the correct position in order to congratulate the user upon completion. Furthermore, knowing how to do that will allow me to be able to randomize and shuffle the image as well - which I have yet to implement.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JEightPuzzleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private int width;
    private int height;

    int position[][];
    private Image image1;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JButton[][] listOfBtn = new JButton[3][3];

    public JEightPuzzleFrame(String Title, String Source){

         position = new int[][] {
                 {0, 1, 2}, 
                 {3, 4, 5}, 
                 {6, 7, 8}};    

         centerPanel = new JPanel();
         centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0)); // 3x3 grid
         add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         // Read the image from folder
        BufferedImage image=null;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(Source));
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Image not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }       
        // get the height and width of the image for the window size
         width = image.getWidth();
         height = image.getHeight();

         for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                 if ( i == 2 && j == 1) {
                     listOfBtn[2][1] = new JButton();
                     centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1]);
                 } else {
                     listOfBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                     listOfBtn[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                     centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[i][j]);
                     Image source = (Image) image;
                      image1 = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                             new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/3, 
                                 (width/3)+1, height/3)));
                     listOfBtn[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(image1));
                     listOfBtn[i][j].setVisible(true);
                 }
             }
         }     
        validate();
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle(Title);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the image
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
    public void shuffle(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            new JEightPuzzleFrame("puzzle", "picture.png");
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

     JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Dimension size = button.getSize();

        int labelX = listOfBtn[2][1].getX();
        int labelY = listOfBtn[2][1].getY();
        int buttonX = button.getX();
        int buttonY = button.getY();
        int buttonPosX = buttonX / size.width;
        int buttonPosY = buttonY / size.height;
        int buttonIndex = position[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];

        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == size.height ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 3;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1], buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == -size.height ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 3;
             centerPanel.remove(labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1], buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 1;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1], buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == -size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 1;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1], labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();
        }
        if(labelY == buttonY && labelX == buttonX) {
            System.out.println("Congrats");
        }
 }
     }
```

Comment: You might reconstruct the image formed by the puzzle pieces, then get a byte array of the data of each `BufferedImage` and directly compare them as a 'brute force' approach.  OTOH it would be better to keep a model to represent the parts of the puzzle, and it would be the responsibility of the model to determine a winning arrangement of tiles.

Comment: keep an array of the current position of the pieces. Update & validate it on every move

Comment: After every move recreate the image from the puzzle and check if it equals the original image.

Comment: I have thought about the array idea, but I can't see how I could change it since I don't fully understand how my actionPerformed works because that was given to me

Comment: *"I don't fully understand how my actionPerformed works"* `<head-desk />`  The first thing you need to do is *fully understand how the actionPerformed works*..

Comment: I'm just asking for help is all. It does not mean I've stopped working on it entirely

Comment: Keep in mind for this type of game, you just can't randomly shuffle the pieces and then place them on the board. It may result in an unsolvable game.  One workaround is to start off with the puzzle solved, and then programmatically move random pieces n times to create a shuffle.  Not sure if this is an optimal approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cropping the Image and pasting it on buttons in the constructor, have an array of images which would contain list of cropped images, in (a pre-defined) order. Also remember to associate a name/number to the Image (can be done by creating a different class having Image and its original position in the full image as member variables of that class).

Now, at the end of your action performed, iterate through all your buttons and get the name of the image attached to it. If all the images are set correctly (as per the original full image),  a concatenation of all their names (in order) would always be the same (independent of the Image used), and hence can be used to determine the final 'winning' condition.

Answer (score 0):

Number you buttons before you shuffle call the containers getcomponents store the array to compare to after each move

Answer (score 0):

Have an array of cropped images and array of equal number of buttons.

```
BufferedImage image[] = new BufferedImage[noOfImages];
JButton buttons[] = new JButton[image.length];
```

Now using `java.util.Random` class, generate random index for images and set it to the button at that index.

```
// Randomizing algorithm. I don't expect you to copy the same code. Just for you to understand the logic.

Random rand = new Random(); 
int index;

/ We'll iterate through each button.
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        // Pick up a random image.
        do {

            index = rand.nextInt(images.length); // Generate a random number from 0 to images.length -1
            // We will set this index position from the image array to null after setting the icon to a button, so that same picture is not selected for some other button.
        } while(images[index] != null);


        button[i].setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(images[index])); // Set the image.
        images[index] = null; // coz you don't want the same image to be set to other buttons again.
}
```

Comment: @Adita See my comment in the OP about shuffling the puzzle.

Comment: Well, yeah. But this could be for a start. And, we cannot spoon feed. We just gave a randomizing technique. Latter part is his. And after all this is just a demo code. not intended to be copied and pasted as I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JEightPuzzleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private int width;
    private int height;     
    private int position[][];
    private int count[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};  // keep track of where the pieces are 
    private Image image1;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JButton[][] listOfBtn = new JButton[3][3];
    private String Source;
    private String Title;
    private int ShuffleCount;

    public JEightPuzzleFrame(String Title, String Source){
        this.Source = Source;
        this.Title = Title;

        ShuffleCount = 0;
        if (ShuffleCount == 0){
            ShuffleCount++;
            set();

        }else{
            shuffle();
        }
    }
    private Image getIcon(int i, int j){
         // Read the image from folder
        BufferedImage image=null;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(Source));
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Image not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }       
        // get the height and width of the image for the window size
         width = image.getWidth();
         height = image.getHeight(); 
         Image source = (Image) image;
         image1 = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                 new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/3, 
                     (width/3)+1, height/3)));
         return image1;
    }
    private void set(){
        position = new int[][] {
                {0, 1, 2}, 
                {3, 4, 5}, 
                {6, 7, 8}};

         centerPanel = new JPanel();
         centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 0)); // 3x3 grid
         add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         // Read the image from folder
        BufferedImage image=null;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(Source));
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Image not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }       
        // get the height and width of the image for the window size
         width = image.getWidth();
         height = image.getHeight(); 
    /*  for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if ( i == 2 && j == 1) {
                    listOfBtn[2][1] = new JButton();
                    centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1]);
                } else {
                 listOfBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                 listOfBtn[i][j].addActionListener(this);
                 centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[i][j]);
                 Image source = (Image) image;
                  image1 = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                            new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/3, 
                                (width/3)+1, height/3)));
                    listOfBtn[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(image1));
                    listOfBtn[i][j].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        } */
         // Set up for initial Game        
         //Button 1
         listOfBtn[0][0] = new JButton();
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][0]);
         count [0] = 9;
         // Button 2
         listOfBtn[0][1] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[0][1].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][1]);
         listOfBtn[0][1].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(0,0)));
         listOfBtn[0][1].setVisible(true);
         count[1] = 1;
         //Button 3
         listOfBtn[0][2] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[0][2].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][2]);
         listOfBtn[0][2].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(0,1)));
         listOfBtn[0][2].setVisible(true);
         count[2] = 2;
       //Button 4
         listOfBtn[1][0] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[1][0].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[1][0]);
         listOfBtn[1][0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(1,1)));
         listOfBtn[1][0].setVisible(true);
         count[3] = 5;
       //Button 5
         listOfBtn[1][1] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[1][1].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[1][1]);
         listOfBtn[1][1].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(1,2)));
         listOfBtn[1][1].setVisible(true);
         count[4] = 6;
       //Button 6
         listOfBtn[1][2] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[1][2].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[1][2]);
         listOfBtn[1][2].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(0,2)));
         listOfBtn[1][2].setVisible(true);
         count[5] = 3;
       //Button 7
         listOfBtn[2][0] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[2][0].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][0]);
         listOfBtn[2][0].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(1,0)));
         listOfBtn[2][0].setVisible(true);
         count[6] = 4;
       //Button 8
         listOfBtn[2][1] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[2][1].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][1]);
         listOfBtn[2][1].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(2,0)));
         listOfBtn[2][1].setVisible(true);
         count[7] = 7;
       //Button 9
         listOfBtn[2][2] = new JButton();
         listOfBtn[2][2].addActionListener(this);
         centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[2][2]);
         listOfBtn[2][2].setIcon(new ImageIcon(getIcon(2,1)));
         listOfBtn[2][2].setVisible(true);
         count[8] = 8;

        validate();
        setSize(width, height);
       setTitle(Title);
       setResizable(false);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center the image
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);
    }
    public void shuffle(){
        set();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new JEightPuzzleFrame("Puzzle", "image.png");   
            System.out.println();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

     JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Dimension size = button.getSize();

        int emptyX = listOfBtn[0][0].getX();
        int emptyY = listOfBtn[0][0].getY();

        int buttonX = button.getX();
        int buttonY = button.getY();
        int buttonPosX = buttonX / size.width;
        int buttonPosY = buttonY / size.height;
        int buttonIndex = position[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];

        if (emptyX == buttonX && (emptyY - buttonY) == size.height ) {          

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 3;

             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][0], buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();

             int a = count[buttonIndex];
             count[buttonIndex] = count[labelIndex];
             count[labelIndex] = a;              
        }

        if (emptyX == buttonX && (emptyY - buttonY) == -size.height ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 3;
             centerPanel.remove(labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][0], buttonIndex);

             centerPanel.validate();
             int a = count[buttonIndex];
             count[buttonIndex] = count[labelIndex];
             count[labelIndex] = a; 
        }

        if (emptyY == buttonY && (emptyX - buttonX) == size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 1;        
             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][0], buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);                                 
             centerPanel.validate(); 
             int a = count[buttonIndex];
             count[buttonIndex] = count[labelIndex];
             count[labelIndex] = a; 
        }

        if (emptyY == buttonY && (emptyX - buttonX) == -size.width ) {

             int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 1;            
             centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
             centerPanel.add(listOfBtn[0][0], labelIndex);
             centerPanel.add(button,labelIndex);
             centerPanel.validate();

             int a = count[buttonIndex];
             count[buttonIndex] = count[labelIndex];
             count[labelIndex] = a; 
        } 
        if(count[0] == 1 &&
                count[1] == 2 &&
                count[2] == 3 &&
                count[3] == 4 &&
                count[4] == 5 &&
                count[5] == 6 &&
                count[6] == 7 &&
                count[7] == 8 &&
                count[8] == 9){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(centerPanel,"Good job! Hit ok to scramble");
            shuffle();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i have figured out how to keep track of the buttons via the action listener. The next step is to be able to shuffle them upon solving the initial layout. The professor requires the initial set up to be that way so he can solve it easily, but it needs to be shuffled after he has done that.